# use pip to install django with error of proxy on win7

Tags: python, django, pip, http-proxy

I followed my colleague's method to install django by pip (python2.7), she succeeded, I got a error message "Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.". but i can browse the web via proxy with the same domain account.

Following command I used in cmd:

```
set http_proxy=domain\username:password@proxyhost:port
set https_proxy=domain\username:password@proxyhost:port
pip install django
```

the last segment of error messages as below:

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))
>   after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',
>   error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required (
>   Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to
>   the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )',))': /simple/django/

I also tried follow cmd, and got same error message as above:

```
pip install django --proxy domain\username:password@proxyhost:port
```

Comment: sometimes it's the simple things... this is Windows (I'm assuming since you said cmd and used set vs export), and I forget how it handles it but you might want to try domain\\username versus domain\username.  Also, it's a little annoying because you won't get the dependencies but you could download the packages by hand and do something like pip install ./django-<stuff>.zip

Comment: thanks Foon for your quickly replying. I tried domain\\username also and got the same error message. I just want to try a simple way to install django as beginning by pip online. actually, there is another required python package which have many dependence packages to be installed on my local machine(win7). I won't to do that one by one.

Answer (score -1):

I just used another proxy with same domain account, the error message disappeared, and every thing is going well.